# Sencha Cmd (windows) build error 'not a recognized Sencha SDK or application folder'

Tags: extjs4.2, sencha-cmd

I am having trouble getting Sencha Cmd to work. I tried to follow the instructions [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/command) and [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/command_app).

My ExtJs directory is located at `D:\Users\denni_000\bin\Sencha\Complete\1.0.3.25\ext-4.2.2-ent\ext-4.2.2.44`

First, I installed Sencha Cmd to this directory: `D:\Users\denni_000\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.1.45`

Next, I opened a command prompt at that directory, and ran the command:

`sencha -sdk D:\Users\denni_000\bin\Sencha\Complete\1.0.3.25\ext-4.2.2-ent\ext-4.2.2.44 generate app Test E:\Test`

So far, all seems okay. This generated a directory at E:\Test. I changed to the E:\Test directory in my command prompt, and ran the following command:

`sencha app build`

I got the following error:

`[ERROR] The current working directory (e:\Test) is not a recognized Sencha SDK or application folder`

I don't understand...didn't I just create that application folder? When I browse to the E:\Test directory, it looks the way I would expect it to look. It has the following directories:

- .sencha
- app
- build
- ext
- overrides
- packages
- sass

Each of the directories seems to be populated. The E:\Test directory also has the following files:

- app.js
- app.json
- bootstrap.css
- bootstrap.js
- bootstrap.json
- build.xml
- index.html
- Readme.md

Comment: Is this the first installation of Sencha CMD on your system?  If your environment variables contains an old installation of sencha cmd that might be causing this issue.

Comment: I am pretty sure I've installed it before, but this is the first that I've tried to use it. Uninstall shows that I only have one instance installed right now. Will uninstalling and then re-installing reinitialize the environment variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled and re-installed. That fixed the issue. Sean Fahey's answer may be worth looking into if you have this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this same issue, except on OS X, and the fix was to remove the reference to the old Sencha SDK Tools from my $PATH, like what Macy Abbey suggests in the question comment.

For Windows, you can edit the environment variables, here's how you get at those: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml but in case anyone on OS X needs an answer you can edit the $PATH by calling

`vi ~/.bash_profile`

from the Terminal.  I commented out the lines that looked like this:

```
# export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3:$PATH
# export SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA3="/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3"
```

The latest version of Sencha Cmd's variables were already present, and looked like

```
export PATH=/Users/username/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.2.67:$PATH
export SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0="/Users/username/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.2.67"
```

Then I ran

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

to reload the values.  I still had to open a new Terminal window to get the `sencha` command to run from the new location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up just uninstalling and re-installing to fix the problem.